# Dropdown from Googlesheet that updates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to create a google sheets form so that users from a given list can freely join and make groups of 3.

In Sheet1, they can select their names from dropdowns. Once they selected one, their email will show up automatically below their name. The list of emails and names is given in Sheet2.

[image: i1]

[image: i2]

[image: i3]

**My question**: How to employ this so that if a user already selected their name, then their name will immediately be removed from the other dropdowns (so another user will not accidentally select it)?

To make dropdowns, I used Data Validation and select the range of names in Sheet2.

To make emails showing up once a name selected, I tried:

[image: i4]

But I don't know a simple way to remove a name from dropdowns if it was selected.

I guess we can use Filter and Index-Match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to set up dropdowns that remove selected values.
Here is a screenshot of my example:

[image: Screenshot1]

In E2:E I have put a list of all available names.  In D2:D, I have used this formula to output all names not used in A2 where the dropdown list will be:

> =FILTER(E2:E,A2<>E2:E,A5<>E2:E,A8<>E2:E)

(`FILTER` formula selects all values in E2:E that do not equal A2,A5, and A8.)

Then in A2,A5, and A8 I have set up a Data Validation-Dropdown from a Range.  The dropdown range is D2:D.  Once a name is selected in one of the dropdowns, the name disappears from D2:D.

One caveat, once a name is selected from the list, an Invalid error appears in the corner of the dropdowns since the name in the dropdown is no longer in the dropdown range; the `FILTER` formula has removed it.  (It is not an issue, but I know it bothers some people.)  I don't know a way around that, however.  Maybe Apps Scripts?

**New update based on question and OP's added screenshots**

Here is a screenshot of my sheet setup that better imitates given example.

[image: Screenshot2]

And the following formula should work in your dropdown range:

> =FILTER(H2:H,COUNTIF(B2:D,H2:H)<1)

Then it is easy to extend the validation down by highlight A2:D3 and dragging down those cells as necessary.

Comment: How to handle the situation if I have 100 rows? In your formula, we need to manually write A2,A5,....

Comment: @user36548 I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: Were you able to test this out?